Messaging board (forum platform) with voice messaging
I am looking for a way to exchange voice messages with another person by having the option record our messages under different topic threads. We are currently communicating over Facebook Messenger but since we are discussing many different topics, it becomes confusing to track the conversations. I am looking for a platform similar to forum boards, where we could set up different topics (threads) and exchange voice messages under each different thread.
What I have discovered so far are https://voicethread.com and https://slack.com, any other suggestions?
